# PHP SQL request returning null value

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm just starting PHP and keep returning null for my SQL query. I am successfully connected to the database and have copied and pasted the query even straight from the database.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "customerbasics";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `orders`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result == NULL){
    
    echo 'No results';
};
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo 'Rows returned';
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is what the browswer prints:

Update: Error checking added:

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No database selected

Comment: It might have `null` data

Comment: You should be using a type check; `$var === NULL`

Comment: Please enable error reporting and then update the question with the error. [How to get the error message in mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/4178487)?

Comment: you have a typo; remove the semicolon from your IF clause `};`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Comment: You need to specify a database from which you select. You would know that if you enabled mysqli error reporting

Comment: You also need to remove the extra `}` you have hanging around.... tidy up your code

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @Martin, while that should be corrected, it is actually legal syntax.

Comment: @Martin its not clean but just trying to print some results

Comment: @JasonK I have updated with the error! Thanks!

Comment: Don't change the question once you received answers. If you have a follow up problem then you can search online for that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the fourth parameter to your connection function

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

You have forgotten the database name in your connection. For more information, you can go [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). Plus I recommend you to learn [PDO or prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to select database before executing a query:

```
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
```

Then execute your query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `orders`";
```

Other way, you can also specify database name directly every executing a query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbname.`orders`";
```